# error while trying to run update and upgrade

Tags: updates

I run

```
sudo apt update
```

result 19 packages

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

result

```
dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

(never seen this before)
Is is safe to follow these instructions?

Comment: Yes you can follow above instruction. No harm at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

From the `dpkg` [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html):

```
--configure package... |-a|
If -a or --pending is given instead of package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.

Configuring consists of the following steps:

   1.  Unpack the conffiles, and at the same time back up the old
              conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.

   2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.
```